# Turning off automatic updates on domain

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-server-2016

I am trying to disable Windows Updates from an entire domain using Windows 2016 GPO's, what's the best way to go about this?

Comment: The way it was always done. There is just one GPO section and its pretty self explainatory. Where do you have problems?

Comment: @LPChip Looking in Group Policy Management I don't see any place to turn this off, in GPEdit all I get options for are local GP management not domain wise.

Answer (score 1):

In the windows server 2016, open the Group Policy management, I can see the `Configure Automatic Update`.

You can configure it as `2`, so that it will not automatically download the windows update and install them, and send a reminder to you, then you can decide if you want to update.

The path is: `Computer configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows component\Windows Update`

[image: Configure Automatic Updates]

If you cannot find this group policy, the Administrative Templates could be destroyed, you can download the Windows client Administrative Templates, and save them on the windows server 2016. then the windows server 2016 will have the same administrative templates as the clients.

You can download them and know how to use in [How to create and manage the Central Store for Group Policy Administrative Templates in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3087759/how-to-create-and-manage-the-central-store-for-group-policy-administra)